# What Disassembler would I use on a ASP dll?

Tags: dll, asp-classic

I've been tasked with re-writing an old ASP 3.0 app. But it has some propriertary dll's included. I'm not sure what the dll's were written in or how they were created (Interdev? VB 6?) I tried to disassemble them with Reflector but it only works on .NET dll's. Does anyone know how to disassemble a dll used in an ASP app?

Comment: So, why do you even need to decompile the third party dll's? Given that you'll be rewriting the project, surely just utilising them in the same fashion (the only difference is HOW you utilise them within the new project's platform) will be sufficient; The simple fact is 'third party' and 'proprietary' are not 'yours' to decompile and the chances are you're treading on licences - unless your case is different, as many are, this is just a note.

Answer (score 0):

Try running something like PEiD with a good userdb file (exhaustive ones can be found via Google).  This should give you an idea the language that was used to create it.  If it's VB6, you can find look for decompilers with Google, though I'm not sure how well their output will help you.